# Pythonic way in matlab to decompose array to variables

Tags: arrays, matlab

So I want to decompose array to multiple variables.
For example,
I have 'data' array of (136,9) size which is of double type.
I want to decompose the values of data(1,:) to multiple variables something like below:

```
[frm_id,seq_id,xmin,ymin,w,h,temp1,temp2,temp3] = data(1,:);
```

In python it was straightforward, but above code gives following error in matlab:

```
Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy
assignment.
```

I can go with something like

```
frm_id = data(1,1);
seq_id = data(1,2);
%ect
```

But I do believe there must be matlab (more neat) way  to do this operation.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that in Matlab. Why is `frm_id = data(1,1);
seq_id = data(1,2);` not OK? because it does not look neat?

Comment: Yep, I need to write data(j,index) 9 times :) . So I am looking for something more neat

Comment: If you want to assign each of the 9 columns to a new array, then you have to write 9 assignments. Maybe consider using another data structure so you only have to write it once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [num2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert the matrix to a cell array then copy contents of the cell to each variable:

```
C = num2cell(data,1);
[frm_id,seq_id,xmin,ymin,w,h,temp1,temp2,temp3] = C{:};
```

Comment: Didn't know cell array can be used like this, which is brilliant. Just a thought through my mind. Is the underlying returned value of a function a cell type?

Comment: @Anthony Which function? The returned value of num2cell is a  cell type:)

Comment: any function. I've realised my question is off-topic already.

Comment: @rahnema1 Brilliant, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest you to create a function like this:

```
function [frm_id,seq_id,xmin,ymin,w,h,temp1,temp2,temp3] = myfunction (data)

frm_id = data(:,1);
seq_id = data(:,2);
xmin = data(:,3);
ymin = data(:,4);
w = data(:,5);
h = data(:,6);
temp1 = data(:,7);
temp2 = data(:,8);
temp3 = data(:,9);
```

so in your main code

`[frm_id,seq_id,xmin,ymin,w,h,temp1,temp2,temp3] = myfunction(data);`